# Existe alguma especificação para autenticação em servidores Websocket?

Tags: segurança, autenticação, websocket

Eu estava pensando como seria um processo de autenticação em um servidor Websocket.

Pretendo usar a API do Javascript para Websocket. Porém eu gostaria de ter um acesso mais restrito e controlado em relação às aplicações que vão ter conexão a esse servidor. O problema é que, uma vez que o Websocket é uma camada à parte da aplicação (ou seja, o Websocket não tem acesso à sessão da aplicação), ele "não sabe" que se o usuário autenticado está ou não autenticado na outra camada.

Eu gostaria de saber quais são os meios para se restringir um acesso a um Websocket.

Por exemplo: Quero que, em uma aplicação, onde eu notifico o usuário o status da sua compra, ele tenha acesso a essa informação em tempo real através do Websocket. Só que eu preciso que esse possa ser "confirmado" como sendo o mesmo que está autenticado na minha aplicação.

Existe alguma técnica ou alguma recomendação específica em relação à autenticações em servidores Websocket?

Pensei em implementar algum tipo de token. Seria uma boa opção?

**Edição**:

Num [artigo que li na internet](https://auth0.com/blog/auth-with-socket-io/) sobre autenticação em Websockets, encontrei um trecho que, traduzido, diz o seguinte:

> É um equívoco comum de que um usuário autenticado no aplicativo web de hospedagem também é autenticado no fluxo de soquete. Estes são dois canais completamente diferentes

Comment: Não poderia simplesmente usar o mesmo cookie de sessão da aplicação? Não entendi a restrição que você mencionou, "o Websocket não tem acesso à sessão da aplicação".

Comment: Wallace talvez isto ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api, http://blog.stratumsecurity.com/2016/06/13/websockets-auth/

Comment: @Bacco exemplo: Uso backend do Laravel no server, porém gostaria de usar o Websocket (que não tem acesso aos mesmos dados).